# Library for Medial Axis Transformation for polygon with holes in C++

Tags: c++

I need to perform the Medial Axis Transformation of a polygon with holes. Something like this:

https://florissteenkamp.github.io/MAT-Demo/

Do you know any implementation of such algorithm in C++?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic according to the [help] guidelines.

Comment: Probably using CGAL library.